# How do I show a non-full screen View Controller on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

When you click the Share button from Safari and choose 'Reminders', you are presented with a nice windowed ViewController with navigation elements. I am completely stumped as to how to go about doing something like this!

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

[image]

Comment: this type we can create UIActivity Controller or UIPopOverController or customUIVIew, ref in google you get multiple answer related to this

Comment: You can add a VC with transparent background.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The ActivityController is the sheet that leads onto this ViewController; I'm familiar with that. I'm looking for a way to show a View like the one shown in the screenshot. The only documentation I can find for something like this indicates to the Form Sheet on iPad only.